# JQuery Ajax not working in JSP with Struts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to create a web app demo with the feature of Ajax. However, the Ajax seems not working using JQuery.

I have not given any response yet, but I thought that the alert should be working. However, nothing happens after I clicked the button.

Maybe there is something wrong in the Ajax parameter? I am still not clear how to pass variable from Ajax to action and another way around.

**JQuery:**

```xml
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#select").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/db/database!selectAll.action',
                data:'{}',
                type:'POST',
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
        $("#delete").click(function() {
            alert("aa");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML TAG:**

```html
<input id="select"type="button" value="select"/>
```

**`Action`:**

```java
package com.rwy.demo.web.db;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.rwy.demo.bean.Person;
import com.rwy.demo.service.PersonService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by cbl on 2016/1/22.
 */
public class DatabaseAction extends ActionSupport{
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    public void selectAll() {
        List<Person> personList = personService.selectAllPerson();    
    }
    public void update() {

    }
    public void delete() {

    }
    public void add() {

    }    
}
```

Comment: try to remove "data:'{}',"

Comment: @willie   still not working, thanks for response

Comment: type:'POST', to change 'Get' , in fact you can check http://www.javatpoint.com/ajax-example-with-database , hopefully it can help you

Comment: @willie I have tried this as well.

Comment: post mean you have to send data to server and the server has to get this , but in you back end code didn't have it

Comment: Which version of S2? Have you enabled DMI?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax to action an all way around passing parameters instead of json and return json results. You could use [Struts2 JQuery plugin](https://github.com/struts-community-plugins/struts2-jquery/wiki) along with [Struts2 JSON plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/json-plugin.html). It has tags that you can use in JSP to generate HTML and jQuery content when the page is rendered. This way is preferable because you need to write *less* javascript code and get less errors doing so. For example a basic ajax call

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
> <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <sj:head/>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="div1">Div 1</div>
>     <s:url id="ajaxTest" value="/AjaxTest.action"/>
>
>     <sj:a id="link1" href="%{ajaxTest}" targets="div1">
>       Update Content
>     </sj:a>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

There you can add parameters to the URL

```
<s:url id="ajaxTest" value="/AjaxTest.action" escapeAmp="false"><s:param name="id" value="123"/></s:url>
```

Runnable example: [Remote Link](https://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase)