# How to pass result from action to ajax in Struts2

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, configuration, struts2

I have the following action, I want to pass name to the ajax response. How could I do it ?

```java
public class DatabaseAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String name;


    public void selectAll() {
        name="aa";

    }
    public void update() {

    }
    public void delete() {

    }
    public void add() {

    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}  
}
```

I am using JQuery to write the ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"/db/database!selectAll.action",
            type:"POST",
            dateType:"JSON",
            success:function(name){
                alert(name);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        alert("delete");
    });
});
```

alert is invoked, but empty result is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Ajax not working in JSP with Struts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939790/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-jsp-with-struts)

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke an action method, this method should return `String` value as a result. This result should have a name and should be configured to the action config or configured globally. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875911/573032) answer to learn more how to configure global results. Local results should be configured to the action config. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27147358/573032) answer if you need more information about local results.

The code:

```
public String selectAll() {
    name="aa";
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

The configuration:

```
<action name="database" class="com.example.DatabaseAction" method="selectAll">
   <result type="json"/>
</action>
```